# Converting MrSID files to other formats in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster-conversion, geotiff-tiff, mrsid

I have some large MRSID files of counties in TN. They are 3 banded, about 4 - 7 GB, and 3rd generation.

I've been in the process of converting them to 3 banded TIFF files using Export Raster Data.  I want to eventually discern agricultural use from them.  The conversion process normally takes over 2 hours.

Is there a better method than this?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: Have you tried a tool called Copy Raster? Uncheck Building Pyramids in the environment setting

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the discussion, but the easiest way to do any conversion of a MrSid file is to download the free web browser plugin from Lizard Tech who created the MrSid file format.  You can get it here: https://www.lizardtech.com/gis-tools/plug-ins